# RPM packaging RPM file is zero?

Tags: makefile, rpmbuild

I did RPM packaging and obtained rpm file and src.rpm file by `rpmbuild -ba ***.spec`.

But, when i type `rpm -qi ***.rpm`. Computer screen displayed that size of rpm package is zero. Also, when I type `rpm -qa | grep ***(name of rpm file)`, etc, there was no problem. What happened? There is a spec file problem?

This is my spec file------------------------------------------

```
Summary : Spec file for making RPM file for ****!
Name : ***
Version : 0.0.1
Release : 1
Source : ***-0.0.1.tar.gz
Prefix : /rpm
Group : Applications/Engineering
License : ******
BuildRoot : /home/users/tmdcjf9119/rpm/tmp

%description
.....

%prep
%setup

%build


%install

make -> there is a makefile in source file and when i compiled with this makefile, objective file and execute(?!) file was made.

%files
```

Comment: Did you install the rpm package you built? What does `rpm -qpi file.rpm` say? What about `rpm -qpl file.rpm`? `rpm -qi` queries installed packages so `rpm -qi file.rpm` should have given you a `package file.rpm is not installed` message.

Comment: Yes. I installed the rpm package i built. Also, when i type rpm -qpl ***.rpm, they say "/usr/bin/***(name of rpm package)",

Comment: and when i type rpm -qpi ***.rpm, they say that Name        : ***(name)                       Relocations: /rpm 
Version     : 0.0.1                             Vendor: (none)
Release     : 1                             Build Date: Tue 28 Apr 2015 04:42:15 PM KST
Install Date: (not installed)               Build Host: //////////
Group       : Applications/Engineering      Source RPM: *****-0.0.1-1.src.rpm
Size        : 0                                License: *******
Signature   : (none)
Summary     : Spec file for making RPM file for *******!
Description :
.....

Comment: Does the `/usr/bin/****` file exist? Does it have a non-zero size? Is that the entire `%files` section of the spec file or are there actually files listed there? What does the `%install` section look like? Does it install to the buildroot or the system directly? Did you build as root or some other user?